# Integrating ffmpeg with qtcreator on windows

Tags: windows, qt, ffmpeg

I am making simple application just calling ffmpeg `av_register_all` in qt project ffmpegexample `main.cpp` but i am getting the following error:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _av_register_all referenced in function _main

My `.pro` file is as follows:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui


QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

INCLUDEPATH = -I D:/ffmpeg/dev/include

LIBS += -LD:/ffmpeg/shared/bin
LIBS += -LD:/ffmpeg/dev/lib

TARGET = ffmpegexample
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Including the LIBS and DLLs as well as headers from ffmpeg static/dev builds from [this](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) location.

My main file is below:

```
 #include <QCoreApplication>
 extern "C" {
 #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
 #include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>
 #include <libavutil/timestamp.h>
 #include <libavformat/avformat.h>
 }

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
 QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

 av_register_all();

 return a.exec();
 }
```

also run qmake to generate `Makefile.debug`
and also copied all the dlls and .libs in folder where project `main.cpp` is there
but that also didn't help
i am getting error:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _av_register_all referenced in function _main File not found main.obj

Don't understand why `main.obj` is not getting generated

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

What I put in my project is this:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$(FFMPEG_DEV_PATH)\include
LIBS += -L$$(FFMPEG_DEV_PATH)\lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lswscale -liconv
```

to avoid the error you've got